# Testing a module patterned JavaScript code with mocha

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, d3.js, mocha.js

I made a small library for which I want to write the test cases. Please note, this is the first time I am going to write unit test cases :)

My library is a small charting library using d3.js to plot a chart. It's a 200 line code written using module patter like this below (just a sample):

```
var graph = (function() {
var a, b, c;

function x() {
    //uses a
}

function y() {
    uses a, b and possibly calls x
}

function plotChart() {
    //uses c;
},

function plotAxis() {
    //uses a,b
}

function validate() {
    //validates values
}

return {
    createChart: function(options) {
        //calls validate,
        //calls plotChart
        //calls plotaxis
        .
        .
        .
        .

    }
}
```

What is the best way to start with unit testing this kinda code. Most of the functions like a, b,c, plotGraph, plotAxis etc are private functions which are not exposed to outside world.

Plus, is mocha is a good choice? My aim is to get a taste of unit testing and then gain experience by delving deeper. Please suggest.

Comment: anybody care to comment for voting for closure?

Comment: What are you exposing as a public API? Start testing that. The outside in strategy usually helps to test it with the point of view of who is going to use your library.

Comment: right. So I am only exposing one public method 'createChart' that takes a few options. So no need to test the private methods?

Comment: If the `createChart` is returning an object, then test the methods of that object too.

Answer (score 0):

Mocha is appropriate for this.  See the [docs](https://mochajs.org) for the browser boilerplate; I'd suggest using [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io) with [karma-mocha](http://npmjs.com/package/karma-mocha), or a similar tool, to automate this.  You will also need to include an assertion library since Mocha does not include one; [Chai](http://chaijs.com) is a popular choice.

[Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) is similar in syntax to Mocha + Chai.  It's more of a "all-in-one" framework.

Assuming `graph` is a global variable (assigned to `window.graph`), you could write a test such as the following in either Jasmine or Mocha:

```
describe('graph', function () {
  describe('method', function () {
    describe('createChart()', function () {
      it('should return x', function () {
        var retval = graph.createChart();
        // assert return value
      });

      it('should throw an exception if y', function () {
        // assert exception thrown when called with some params
      });

      it('should mutate z', function () {
        // etc.
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Would suggest reading a basic "intro to unit testing" tutorial to get an idea of what assertions to make.  Good luck!